# Inequality bound with $\nabla(\nabla\cdot u)$ or $\nabla \times (\nabla \times u) $

Tags: vector-analysis, curl

I'm studying regularity for linear elasticity problem where I encountered

$\nabla (\nabla \cdot u) = \nabla \times (\nabla \times u) + \Delta u$

I am hoping to find a bound of $\|\nabla (\nabla \cdot u)\|$ with respect to $\|u\|_2$ or any norm of $u$. something like

$\|\nabla (\nabla \cdot u)\|_{L^2} \leq \|\nabla \times (\nabla \times u)\|_{L^2} + \|\Delta u\|_{L^2} \leq f(\|u\|_{H^2}, \|u\|_{H1}, ...)$

But I could not find one. I only manage to show $\|\nabla \times u\|_{L^2} \leq C\|u\|_{H^1}$, I would like to ask is there an inequality for $\|\nabla(\nabla\cdot u)\|_{L^2}$ and $\|\nabla \times (\nabla \times u) \|_{L^2}$ with respect to $\|u\|_{H^2}$.

Comment: Think one-dimensional, see if it makes sense: Is there a bound to $\frac{d^2u}{du^2}$ with respect to $|u|$? This isn't a full answer, as things could happen in higher dimensions, but it will tell you what you can likely expect.

Comment: @Arthur thank you for the hint. For one dimension, I think I can make use of Sobolev embedding. Hence I could deal with $\Delta u$ too. But I'm not sure how I can deal with $\nabla \times (\nabla \times u)$

Comment: This is way too vague as is: What norms do you use on $\nabla (\nabla\cdot u)$, and which ones on $u$? It seems like $\|u\|_2, \| u\|_1$ denote a Sobolev norm, but I can't really tell.

Comment: @Jose27 sorry, I meant L^2 norm on $\nabla (\nabla \cdot u)$ and H^2 and H^1 norm on u.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but since all your operators (cross product and laplacian) are linear on $u$, you can just take $f(\| u\|_{H^2})=C\| u\|_{H^2}$, for an appropriate constant $C$ by the triangle inequality.

Comment: @Jose27, could you elaborate a bit more? I know $\|\Delta u\|_{L^2} \leq C\|u\|_{H^2}$, but I cannot find a way to show $\|\nabla \times (\nabla \times u)\|_{L^2} \leq C\|u\|_{H^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to look at this is to recall that
$$
\nabla \times (\nabla \times u) = 
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
e_1 & e_2 & e_3\\
\partial_1 & \partial_2 & \partial_3\\
v_1 & v_2 & v_3 
\end{pmatrix}
,
$$
where $v=\nabla \times u$, and $e_i$ are the canonical vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Put another way we have
$$
\nabla \times(\nabla \times u)= \left( \partial_2 v_3 - \partial_3 v_2, \partial_3 v_1 - \partial_1 v_3, \partial_1 v_2- \partial_2 v_1 \right).
$$
Now, for instance, lets focus on the first term: We know
$$
v= \left( \partial_2 u_3- \partial_3 u_2, \partial_3 u_1 - \partial_1 u_3, \partial_1 u_2 - \partial_2 u_1\right),
$$
and so
$$
\partial_2 v_3 - \partial_3 v_2 = \partial_2(\partial_1 u_2 - \partial_2 u_1) - \partial_3(\partial_3 u_1- \partial_1 u_3),
$$
and it's clear from the triangle inequality that the $L^2$ norm of this quantity is controlled by the $H^2$ norm of $u$.